# Class that is member of another class is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, null, lazy-loading

I am working on a C# WPF project using Entity Framework code first.

I have a class that has an instance of another class as its member. I am trying to access the value of a property of the member class. I can get the value this way:

```
var com = context.MyParentClass.Where(p => (p.Identity == id)).Select(c =>
                            new
                            {
                                id = c.Identity,
                                PropertyValue = c.MyChildClass.PropertyValue
                            }
                             );

                    foreach(var item in com)
                    {
                        string xx = item.PropertyValue;
                        MessageBox.Show(xx);
                    }
```

But when I try to get the value without the select, the member class is always null:

```
var com = db.MyParentClass.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Identity == id);
                    string xx = com.MyChildClass.PropertyValue; //MyChildClass is null
                    MessageBox.Show(xx);
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? How do I get around the null-problem?

Comment: Is it included in the fetch? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that lazy loading is enabled or not.

1. `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` should be true.
2. `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` should be true.
3. Navigation property should be defined as `public`, `virtual`. The
   context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not defined as
   virtual.

You can use `Include` for eager loading also. Thank you @CodeCaster  for the suggestion.

**Reference**: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: That technically works, but you generally don't want lazy loading. OP just needs `Include()`.

Comment: Yees He can use eager loading also

Comment: That did it, thanks!